# Are programming questions off-topic in SharePoint SE?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

Should questions about creating webparts or modifying the code in server files be relegated to Programmers or StackOverflow?

Comment: On the flip side of that, I wonder about SharePoint dev questions being asked on StackOverflow now, would they promptly be shifted off to here now or just answered despite the overlap?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Anything having to do with SharePoint should be on SharePoint SE. This includes the creation of SharePoint Web Parts and the creation/modifying of SharePoint specific code files.

See this answer from the Area51 Proposal for more information: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/when-should-a-question-be-posted-on-sharepoint-overflow-instead-of-stackoverflow/1062#1062
 -

Comment: +1 Because that was my question.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely not. This is neither a dev forum nor an IT forum. It's all about SharePoint.

Comment: My original response meant the exact opposite of what I intended, when taken in the context of the question. Great start.

Comment: Gentlemen, we can rebuild him. We have the technology.

Comment: I'm lucky I didn't end up with a -ve rep on the new platform.