# Are questions about resources for learning SP development on-topic?

Tags: discussion, tagging, asking-questions

Looking the [SharePoint Stack Exchange tour](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour) I found difficult to ask questions about **references for learning SharePoint development.**

I know there's a [related question with an accepted answer](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6/35471) but I'm wondering if it can be extended for include questions like this one:

> How to Develop an App for add it in SharePoint Online.

Here, the *how to* may be added as a `tag` for classify these kind of questions.

The search results on the internet are abundant and they can solve some development requirements, but, since the *user who ask the question* may not have knowledge in which way the SharePoint custom developments works, I'm hesitating in make this question in the main site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to use the learning tag?